# package.json script words take as commands in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, windows, macos

In my meteor js project, In package.json I have this script

```
"start_with_dev": "MAIL_URL=mongodb.net:45285/local?ssl=true&replicaSet=hhh-dev-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true' meteor run --settings ./config/settings.development.json",
```

This is working fine fine MacOS and Linux, But when I try to run this command in windows with `cross-env`

```
"start_with_dev": "cross-env MAIL_URL=mongodb.net:45285/local?ssl=true&replicaSet=hhh-dev-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true' meteor run --settings ./config/settings.development.json",
```

I am getting this error

> 'replicaSet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

After the & sign windows treat the word as a command.
How do I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there is a `'` missing after `MAIL_URL=`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon no this is a sample code only. ' is there